# .find() Multiple selector cannot add prop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, object

I'm working at a form and I got stuck on this situation.
I cannot add the prop checked on the multiple selector input radio buttons. If i use only one it works.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

```
 var answers = [
        {
            key: 'answerQ1',
            value: 3
        },
        {
            key: 'answerQ2',
            value: 5
        },
        {
            key: 'answerQ3',
            value: 2
        },
        {
            key: 'answerQ4',
            value: 1
        },
        {
            key: 'answerQ5',
            value: 4
        },
    ];

$.map( answers, function( val ) {
        var selector = $('.mark-container').find('input[name=' + val.key + ']').find('input[value=' + val.value + ']');
        selector.prop("checked", true);
        console.log(selector);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an **AND** selector

```
var selector = $('.mark-container').find('input[name=' + val.key + '][value=' + val.value + ']');
```

If you are looking for an **OR** selector

```
var selector = $('.mark-container').find('input[name=' + val.key + '], input[value=' + val.value + ']');
```

For reference, [Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: also found this works also: $('.mark-container').find('input[name=' + val.key + ']').filter('[value='+ val.value +']')